# Mesh opens up its inside after applying Boolean modifier

Tags: modifiers

I have two jaw bone STL files. Both were treated with boolean modifier but one results in non-closed mesh and the other appears to be ok. The two STL files are from two different sources so maybe that makes a difference. But please educate me on why it happens and how to avoid this in the future.

Thank you!

/// BAD ////

[image]

/// Good ///

[image]

Comment: It could be that the jaw mesh is too complex for Boolean to solve; some unexpected things like openings in the mesh, inverted normals in multiple places etc. show that the cut mesh had some problems *before* boolean like [non-manifold](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7910/what-is-non-manifold-geometry) or too complex geometry. If using Blender 2.78+ you can choose Solver method in the Boolean mod options which might help a bit.

Comment: Thanks. I fixed non-manifold, made sure no openings in mesh, and flipped normal to same direction and it works much better now.